# Lock files while process is running

Tags: python, linux

I have skeleton code where the user specifies a `scripts.txt` file that contains service names. Whenever the application is installed, the code automatically generates `.service` files for every entry in `scripts.txt`. These services are placed in `/lib/systemd/system`, so that whenever the machine crashes the application gets restarted.

I would like to add a deinstallation functionality that removes the `.service` files that were created. For that the code has to again look into `scripts.txt`, but if the user changed this file meanwhile, the application will not know which services to remove.

Therefore, I would like to know, if there is a way to lock a file from being edited while a certain process is running?

Comment: I think you may be making this difficult. Adopt a standard naming pattern for your services, so you can easily get a list of services your script has installed just by looking for services with a certain prefix. Then the list of services you need to remove are simply those services that are no longer listed in your `scripts.txt` file.

Comment: This is actually a really easy fix for my problem. Thank you. Feel dumb for not thinking of this :D